# How do you add a Fontawesome icon to a button in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, forms, font-awesome

I am using emailjs and after the email is sent, my Fontawesome icon disappears. I tried a few things, but I can not seem to get the same icon back into the submit button.

It occurs in this line:

```
myform.find("button").text('<i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit');
```

Currently, the output just displays the tag as text. I was hoping I could display the icon instead. Is there a JS trick that can get that to happen?

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `myform` is jquery object:

```
myform.find("button").html('<i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit');
```

I only changed the `.text` function call to `.html` function call

Comment: Thank you... yes, this worked. It was as simple as that. Excellent!!! I'll give you the tick when it becomes available!